# Why does rails app show /public index listing instead of actual app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, virtualhost

How do you set up apache to show the rails app once it is on the server?  My rails app works perfectly on the localhost, but when I go to the external site it gives me the index information

like this

```
Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[TXT]   404.html    21-May-2012 21:38   728      
[TXT]   422.html    21-May-2012 21:38   711      
[TXT]   500.html    21-May-2012 21:38   643      
[IMG]   favicon.ico 21-May-2012 21:38   0    
[TXT]   robots.txt  21-May-2012 21:38   204
```

This is my virtual host information

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin example@example.com
      ServerName server.example.com
      # ServerAlias
      DocumentRoot /var/www/sample_app/current/public
      ErrorLog /var/www/sample_app/error.log

          RailsEnv production
        <Directory "/var/www/sample_app/current/public">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sorry if that is a silly question, but have you set up anything like a Mongrel Cluster, or Passenger, ...?

Comment: yes passenger is up and working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK that might not be it, but here's what [Passenger's documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root) recommends:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mycook.com
    DocumentRoot /webapps/mycook/public
    <Directory /webapps/mycook/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It's clearly stated that MultiViews is **not** compatible with Passenger.

So you could try:

- Removing the Indexes option
- Specifying `-MultiViews` instead of `MultiViews`

To be honest, I've tried adding Indexes to a production app of mine, as I thought that might just be this option that caused the problem, but it didn't change anything... so it's a bit of a "wild guess" that it might fix things on your side.

**UPDATE**
From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923588/directory-listing-instead-of-rails-site-after-passenger-ree-upgrade), what you could try is adding the `PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot` option:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mycook.com
    DocumentRoot /webapps/mycook/public
    <Directory /webapps/mycook/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, but thank you.  You are right about the MultiViews

Comment: OK, sorry it didn't work!
I found this answered question that might help if you're using symlinks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923588/directory-listing-instead-of-rails-site-after-passenger-ree-upgrade

Comment: Re: down vote accepted
 

I was able to solve this using:

PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot

It seems that Passenger no longer handles public directories that are symlinks to your app elsewhere by default. Turning this option on fixed all the issues.

Do you know how to turn this option on?

Comment: looks like the info I need is here.  https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/rails thanks

Comment: All right, well I've updated my answer to address your question too ^^